# To Filter String and Only get the Integers

Tags: python, string, filter

I'm using PYTHON3 my output is like this "200:Just be close at Hand" I only need the 200 is there a way to remove the strings and symbol? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything that's not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to remove anything that's not a number

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "200:Just be close at Hand"
>>> re.sub(r'[^\d]', "", s)
'200'
>>> s = "200:Just be close 33 at Hand 342"
>>> re.sub(r'[^\d]', "", s)
'20033342'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> txt = "200:Just be close at Hand"
>>> txt.split(":")[0]
'200'
```